# JQuery - Why event.target doesn't work in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

just wondering why when i click inside the container the alert popups despite the if statement for it to not show on click.

Also how would I test for the children inside?

https://jsfiddle.net/w8fd3m67/

```js
$(window).on("click", function(event) {
  var container = $("#container");
  if ((event.target) !== container) {
    alert("clicked outside");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 600px;
}

#container {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Cheers

Comment: Because you are comparing a DOM element reference (event.target) with a jQuery object here.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
if($(event.target).is(container))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function to compare the event target to your JQuery element :

```js
$(window).on("click", function(event) {
  var container = $("#container");
  if ($(event.target).is(container)) {
    alert("clicked outside");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 600px;
}

#container {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Comment: What about checking if children are inside? And is this something that has changed with JQuery? Why doesn't my example work? Cheers

Comment: THe target element children are accessible via the `.children()` function. Your example didn't work because you compared a JQuery Object to a DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the `id`. Here `$("#container")` is a jquery object

```js
$(window).on("click", function(event) {
  if ((event.target.id) !== 'container') {
    alert("clicked outside");
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 600px;
}

#container {
  padding: 2rem;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing a DOM element to a jQuery object which will never match. Create a jQuery object out of the target and check if it is a descendant of `#container`. This also works if you have child elements under `#container`.

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w8fd3m67/1/)**

```
$(window).on("click", function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).closest('#container').length == 0){
    alert("clicked outside");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(window).on("click", function(event) {
var container = $("#container");
if ((event.target) !== container[0]) {
    alert("clicked outside");
}});
```